# NullPointerException in struts attribute mapping

Tags: java, struts2, nullpointerexception, mapping

I get a NullPointerException if I call isEmpty() onto an attribute which is referenced in my JSP and the corresponding Action class.

JSP:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Registrieren - WebShop 2.0</title>
<s:head />
</head>
<body>

    <b><s:text name="welcome.title" /></b>

    <s:form action="UserRegister" focusElement="firstname">
        <s:textfield name="firstname" key="prompt.firstname" size="20"


required="true" />
    <s:textfield name="lastname" key="prompt.lastname" size="20"
        required="true" />
    <s:textfield name="username" key="prompt.username" size="20"
        required="true" />
    <s:password name="password" key="prompt.password" size="20"
        required="true" />
    <br>

    <s:submit method="execute" value="Registrieren" align="right" />
</s:form>

<font color="red"> <s:actionerror label="label" />
</font>
```

Action class:

```
package vislabWebShop.controller;

import vislabWebShop.model.User;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -983183915002226000L;

  private String firstname;
  private String lastname;
  private String username;
  private String password;

  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception
  {
    if(getFirstname().isEmpty() || getLastname().isEmpty() || getUsername().isEmpty() || getPassword().isEmpty())
    {
      addActionError(getText("error.register.complete"));
      return INPUT;
    }
    else
    {
      User registeredUser = new User();
      registeredUser.setFirstname(getFirstname());
      registeredUser.setLastname(getLastname());
      registeredUser.setUsername(getUsername());
      registeredUser.setPassword(getPassword());

      addActionMessage(getText("success.register.user"));
      return SUCCESS;
    }
  }

  public String getLastname()
  {
    return lastname;
  }

  private void setLastname(String lastname)
  {
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }

  public String getFirstname()
  {
    return firstname;
  }

  private void setFirstname(String firstname)
  {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }

  public String getUsername()
  {
    return (this.username);
  }

  public void setUsername(String username)
  {
    this.username = username;
  }

  public String getPassword()
  {
    return (this.password);
  }

  public void setPassword(String password)
  {
    this.password = password;
  }
}
```

struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>

    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="ApplicationResources" /> 

    <!-- Add packages here -->

        <package name="vislabWebShop" extends="struts-default">

        <!-- Add your actions here  -->

        <action name="UserForward">
            <result>/pages/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="UserLogin" class="vislabWebShop.controller.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/pages/Welcome.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/Login.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="UserRegister" class="vislabWebShop.controller.RegisterAction">
            <result name="success">/pages/Login.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/Register.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action name="UserRegisterNew">
            <result>/pages/Register.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>


</struts>
```

Two attributes are mapped sucessful. Can attributes also be duplicated in other forms?

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: @Saposhiente if(getFirstname().isEmpty() || getLastname().isEmpty() || getUsername().isEmpty() || getPassword().isEmpty()).

Comment: @MarcelHöll At very first run those fields are  `null` by default. Initialize them like `private String firstname = "";` Or check them for `null` like `getFirstname() == null`

Comment: @Smit Yes, but I need these fields to be set from the JSP. Two fields are set, but the other ones aren't.

Comment: @MarcelHöll Yeah Thats okay. But still you have to `set` them first using `setter` as soon as you get those values from `JSP` pages. Other wise those fields in java backend will be `null`, causing you `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Smit If I initialize all attributes with an empty String "", also if I submit the form on the JSP site two String attributes are not set!

Comment: @Smit Any suggestions?? Always the same: password and username are set throughout the JSP, but lastname and firstname not.

Comment: @MarcelHöll I have never worked with `struts`, But from your `execute()` method code is really not doing that you are expecting it to do. Basically `getFirstname().isEmpty()` statements throwing `NPE` as `getFirstname()` returns `null` and same is going with other `getter methods`. Initialize them atlest to avoid `NPE`. Secondly You are setting the `setter` using `getters`, you should be setting them through `form attributes values` You have `required="true"` in your `JSP` that means form should not be getting submitted until those are filled.

Comment: things appear fine to me, create & try setting other variables.

Comment: The `method="execute"` will not work because you haven't allowed DMI.

Comment: @AleksandrM I have put this code into debug mode and the execute method from the above java class is called successfully. The attributes are set from the struts framework, but if I fill the complete form and submit it, only two attributes in the java class are set.

Comment: Execute method will be called because it is default, not because of `method` attribute of submit tag.

Comment: Password and username attribute are successfully set after submit, but not firstname and lastname. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following was the mistake: In the `RegisterAction.java` I put the `setter` method into `private` and so these methods can't be called from `struts`. Turning them into `public` solved the problem.